# cant import javafx linechart

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart; into my code, but for whatever reason it just keeps coming up as an error. I am currently using Eclipse, but I have also tried the same exact file on NetBeans and neither seems to work. I can use the constructor `LineChart lineChart = new LineChart();` but I am trying to use the `LineChart<X,Y>` class. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Here is the full code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart; // <---- Problem Line
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChart extends Application{
@Override 
public void start(Stage stage){
    stage.setTitle("Test");
    //Axis
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Test Axis");

    //Create chart
    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Test");

    //Series
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("Test Series");

    //Adding the Data
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1,50));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2,60));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3,70));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4,80));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5,90));

    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 400, 300);
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Change your class name from LineChart to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of your class to something other than `LineChart` :

```
public class MyOwnLineChart_2  /* or similar */
```

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.html)